# Convert HTML DOM to image

Tags: java

I am working on a `free Telegram Bot` for prettify code syntax for messaging in telegram but telegram not support `CSS` style so I want to convert this `HTML DOM` to image.I need  library  for converting html to image using java.please say your suggestions.I test `html2image` but has not good graphic after convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks from my friend for down voting me! but i found a good online API for this work. [Convert html to image](https://convertio.co/)